# Apache: how to add a virtual directory to a virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2

We have a Windows server running Apache.

The Apache server is successfully configured to serve 6 sites using name-based virtual hosting.

I need to add a virtual directory to ONE of these sites, and have that directory's default document be a specific file from the site's directory structure (The site uses a CMS that generates fairly unpleasant static URLs, which is why we want to do this).

So, what I want is:

```
http://www.oursite.com/virtual_dir
```

to serve content from

```
http://www.oursite.com/a-page-from-the-cms.html
```

I can't work out how/where to add the statements to create the virtual directory.

Here's a chunk from the httpd-vhosts.conf file so you can see how we have configured what is working so far (IP addresses & URLs have been changed):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
     DocumentRoot "E:/webs/default/"
</VirtualHost>


# Main site

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@oursite.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/webs/www.oursite.com/site/"
    ServerName www.oursite.com
    ErrorLog "E:/webs/www.oursite.com/logs/oursite.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "|C:/Apache/bin/rotatelogs.exe E:/webs/www.www.oursite.com/logs/oursite.com/logs/www.oursite.com/logs/oursite.com-access.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 86400" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive, e.g.

```
Alias /virtual_dir /the/path/on/your/filesystem/to/a-page-from-the-cms.html
```

A more complex solution is to use `mod_rewrite`, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: This only applies to aliasing urls to the filesystem. If you want to alias urls to non-file backed content, you will need to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: what about mod_vhost_alias.?